# Java slackbot - unhandled exception error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, slack, slack-api

Im using the example from the slack dev guide but their example isnt working for me and im not quite sure as to why. I would imagine that involves something with the api token but i cant see any documentation on it.

Heres what i have so far. Im getting an unhandled exception with a red line underneath .start() method

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.slack.api.bolt.App;
import com.slack.api.bolt.jetty.SlackAppServer;

@RestController
public class SlackController {

    @GetMapping("/slack")
    public String slackapp(){
        var app = new App();
        var server = new SlackAppServer(app);
        server.**start();**


        return "hi";
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add `throws Exception` to your `slackapp()` method.

Comment: Just saying: proper handling of exception is a very basic topic in java. Before you start writing code to integrate with a 3rd party service ... you better focus on learning more of the java basics. Playing around is nice, but especially when your code interacts with "real" services somewhere ... you better know 100% what you are doing.

Comment: sounds serious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

surround server.start with a try catch and print the exception:

```
try{

     server.start();

}catch(Exception e){

     e.printStackTrace();

}
```

or add a throws declaration:

```
public String slackapp() throws Exception{
    var app = new App();
    var server = new SlackAppServer(app);
    server.start();


    return "hi";
}
```